# Toggle class, cycling within a group

Tags: jquery

I'm developing a UI with some elements separated into two groups, left and right, that'll be highlighted when clicked, by manipulating data-attributes on them.

If there's an element highlighted when clicking on a second element, the first "lights off" so only the second has the effect.

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/e5ykucte/1/) is where I've come so far:

```js
$( '#wrapper' ).on( 'click', '.box[data-selectable="1"]', function() {

 var $this = $( this );
  
  $this.attr( 'data-selected', ( $this.attr( 'data-selected' ) == '0' ? '1' : '0' ) );
  
 $( '.box' ).not( $this ).attr({
    'data-selected': '0',
    'data-selectable': '1'
  });
});
```

```css
body { margin: 2%; }

#wrapper { display: flex; }

.box {
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
          box-shadow: none;
   
  display: flex;
  height: 150px;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 20px 50px 40px 50px;
  
  -webkit-transition: box-shadow .5s linear;
       -o-transition: box-shadow .5s linear;
     -moz-transition: box-shadow .5s linear;
      -ms-transition: box-shadow .5s linear;
  -kthtml-transition: box-shadow .5s linear;
          transition: box-shadow .5s linear;

  width: 150px;
}

.box[data-selected="1"] {
    -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 0px 20px 16px rgba( 255, 0, 0, 0.8 );
            box-shadow: -1px 0px 20px 16px rgba( 255, 0, 0, 0.8 );

    -webkit-transition: box-shadow .5s linear;
         -o-transition: box-shadow .5s linear;
       -moz-transition: box-shadow .5s linear;
        -ms-transition: box-shadow .5s linear;
    -kthtml-transition: box-shadow .5s linear;
            transition: box-shadow .5s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">

  <div id="a">
    <div class="box" data-offset="1" data-selected="0" data-selectable="1">1</div>
    <div class="box" data-offset="2" data-selected="0" data-selectable="1">2</div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="b">
    <div class="box" data-offset="3" data-selected="0" data-selectable="0">3</div>
    <div class="box" data-offset="4" data-selected="0" data-selectable="0">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Looks good, if not because when selecting an element from the first group (column) an element of the second group can (and need to) be selected as well, so when AJAX calls is made, two elements' data will be sent.

It's a simple rule, always one from the left side and one from the right side. If it helps, think about it like a memory game, only restricted by columns.

And this where I'm stuck as I don't know how to distinguish them.

Comment: I didn't get your name before you deleted your comment/answer. Well, [your approach](https://jsfiddle.net/e5ykucte/2/) worked quite well, except for the fact that now, initially, all the boxes are being allowed to be selected. I've set `data-selectable` as zero because one of the elements of the first group must be selected first. In fact, it was because of this rule that I used event delegation instead of a "normal" click handler

Comment: Updated answer with comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap them in 2 separate groups (div's for example) and initiate your jquery script for each of them. Make sure that when you "lighting-off" you doing it in scope of your group. You can use .parent() for getting to your group element instead of global search (".box"): `$this.parent().find( '.box' ).not( $this )` or you can use '.siblings()': `$this.siblings().not( $this )`

https://jsfiddle.net/e5ykucte/3/

For distinguish purpose, you can use `id` attribute from your parent group element.

```
$this.parent().attr('id')
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e5ykucte/4/

Simply add condition based on your first group name (might be subject to change):

```
 var currentGroup = $this.parent().attr('id');
  if (currentGroup == 'a' && $this.attr('data-selected') == "0") {
      $("div#b .box").attr({
        'data-selectable': '0',
        'data-selected': '0',
        });
  } else {
     $(".box").not( $this ).attr({
      'data-selectable': '1'
    });
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e5ykucte/6/

Comment: Sorry, I realized that I'm not completely solving your issue, that's why I deleted comment. Updated answer.

Comment: Almost. Now it works as intended... for the first time. If a box of the first group is selected and then one of the second is, if the user then de-selecting everything, those of the second group become available for initial choice. That's because of this new part of the third revision data modifies the `data-selectable` unrestrictedly. I believe it should be conditioned with something that my modest knowledge of JS can't figure it out.

Comment: So, what should happen if you deselecting items from the first group? It should remove selected items from 2nd group?

Comment: Precisely, but also if there's nothing selected on the first group, those on the second can't be clicked either, thus the filtering on the selector used when defining the click handler

Comment: Updated with requested features.

Comment: As much I could test, this seems to do the trick but, before finishing, any chance of not needing to hardcode the selectors? Maybe... checking upon the "state" of the `data-selected`?

Comment: You can have state changed in the second group and you will need somehow differentiate those. As an option you can use index of grouping elements but it sounds like even worse solution.

Comment: I see. Well, these `#a` and `#b` do exist in the real code, although with different names, of course, so I guess it won't be a big deal. Thank you for your time.